# TCHAR char problem with cross compile JNI native lib

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I created a JNI project with a native-lib. I developed it on Linux. Now I want to build the same lib on
Windows 10 but now I got errors like:

```
1>..\JNIViie.cpp(334) : error C2664: 'JNIEnv_::NewStringUTF' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const TCHAR *' to 'const char *'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

I tried to compile with and without UNICODE flag. What is the problem here becaue on Linux it compile well.

Comment: You need to undefine both `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE`, I think.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have forgotten the underscore.